# Unable to find key codes for AM and PM. Android

Tags: android, android-timepicker

In Android 5.0
when i create time picker.

I got this error.

> E/TimePickerDelegate﹕ Unable to find keycodes for AM and PM.

Anyone known how to resolve this error?

```
mTimePicker = (TimePicker) mView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);
```

I used New Android Studio.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: @NathanTuggy - it is good to make an effort to understand a problem before reflexively insisting on things. A simple code example may well be unable to demonstrate *this* problem, as it appears tied to the device language.  Specifically, the code which generates this message is in a function in the source code of Android, for which the comment is "Get the keycode value for AM and PM in the current language."  See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.0_r5/core/java/android/widget/TimePickerClockDelegate.java

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Duly noted, but the only current answer indicates that there's some code not seen that is likely related to the problem cause, so while a strict MCVE may not be possible, more code context still seems quite desirable.

Comment: @NathanTuggy the only current answer is likely wrong or at least irrelevant.  The code which really matters here is that within Android itself, not that written by the poster.  Particularly as Mahesh couldn't replicate the problem, I strongly suspect that the triggering condition is merely which language the device is operating in and has nothing to do with the poster's program beyond the fact that they try to use this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Cant getting your exact problem
but if you seen [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) then you must getting that, you should use "a" in date format for dealing with "AM / PM"

And be sure, when you are using "a" for getting am/pm, your hours format should be in "hh" (i.e 12 hour foramat) not in "HH" (i.e 24 hour format). Let us know if you need more help..

Comment: I used default and get this. it's not crash.